# Continuous at a point

Tags: calculus

$F(x,y) =x^2 y /x^2+y^2 , (0,0) $.
The answer is that F is  not continues at $(0,0)$ because

1. $\lim (x,y)>(0,0) ~ f(x,y)$ does not exist
2. $(0,0) \in D_f$

where $D_f$ is the domain of $f$.

I try a method where you let $y=g_1(x)=x$
And $y=g_2(x)=x^2$ which is it to curves that pass the point $(0,0)$ etc 
And the limit is equal which means that the function is exist !

And why does point $(0,0)$ belong to $D_f$ ?

[image]

Comment: Wow the English part and the math part are both not that readable. Would you please take some more time to rephrase the whole question so that your chance of getting a proper help will be much higher?

Comment: Am sorry am not English but I tried my best:)

Comment: You may want to use \frac{}{} to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment. But, I think something is wrong with the way you wrote that function.

Your function simplifies to $F(x,y) = y + y^2$. This is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: How it's simplifies as y+y^2 ?

Comment: $F(x,y)=x^2y/x^2+y^2$. The first term is $x^2y/x^2 = y$. So $F(x,y)=y+y^2$

Comment: How is x square equal y

Comment: $\frac{x^2y}{x^2} = \frac{x^2}{x^2} \times y = 1 \times y = y$.